# Ставится ли запятая после "не знаю"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

*Не знаю, насколько похоже получилось. Я плох в рисовании от руки.*

Answer (score 2):

Сложноподчинённое предложение с придаточным изъяснительным. Запятая ставится между частями СПП.

***Не знаю, насколько похоже получилось.***

Главное предложение НЕ ЗНАЮ - односоставное определённо-личное, союзное слово НАСКОЛЬКО присоединяет придаточное.